# How many spells do I get as a level 7 Druid with 12 Wisdom?

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting, druid

I’m playing my first dnd campaign ever, and I have no clue what I’m doing since I don’t own the player handbook. I’ve figured things out so far, except for how many spells I get. Could someone help me out and tell me?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Since your new to DnD, I strongly suggest  to start with a Level 1 character: this allows you to learn all the abilities of your character at suitable pace, since at level 7 you have several features that may confuse... Is there any particular reason given by your DM to make the party start at lev 7? Anyway, welcome again and if you plan to visit this site I humbly suggest to take a look at [tour] and at [help], even for understanding why your question has been closed! Happy gaming!

Answer (score 1):

From https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/druid#Spellcasting-166:

> You prepare the list of druid spells that are available for you to cast, choosing from the druid spell list. When you do so, choose a number of druid spells equal to **your Wisdom modifier + your druid level** (minimum of one spell).

Your wisdom modifier is +1 and your druid level is 7, so eight spells.  (Your three cantrips are counted separately.)

I advise reading that page carefully, and also using D&D Beyond for character creation.  This will automate many of your decisions.